# LUA : Use table from another file

Tags: lua

I just studied Lua language. I am very confused about it.

I have two file

string.lua

```
STRINGS=
{
    CHARACTER_NAMES =
    {
        web = "webby",
        sac = "sacso",      
    }
}

STRINGS.BUNNYNAMES =
{
    "Brassica",
    "Bunium",
    "Burdock",
    "Carrot",    
}
```

And I have `generate.lua` file for get value form table in `string.lua`.
Then print value.

But I don't know how to acess table form another file. 
I want to use STRINGS and STRINGS.BUNNYNAMES too, 
Please advise me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`string.lua` defines one global variable named `STRINGS` which contains a table.

You need to execute `string.lua` before you can access `STRINGS`. Just do `dofile("string.lua")` for instance.